# android display arabic doc,docx file from sdcard in textView

Tags: android, encoding, bufferedreader

I need to read an arabic docx placed into my sdcard from my android app, and display the text into a textView, i use the code below but the text appears like weird characters. What is the encoding to use other than UTF-8:

```
        File logFile = new File(path + name);
    if (logFile.exists())
    {
       try
       { FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(logFile);
             BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(
                     new InputStreamReader(fIn,"UTF-8"));
             String aDataRow = "";
             String aBuffer = "";
             while ((aDataRow = myReader.readLine()) != null) {
                 aBuffer += aDataRow + "\n";}
             tv.setText(aBuffer); //tv is the textView
             myReader.close(); 
           logFile.createNewFile();
       } 
       catch (IOException e)
       {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

Comment: .doc file have the same problem too

Comment: Okay, what about pdf?

Comment: did you know any third party library to use ?

Comment: `What is the encoding to use other than UTF-8`? **UTF-8** (note that the document itself must have been **saved as** Unicode UTF-8, not with the Windows standard codepage). Also, make sure you use a **font** which has the Arabian glyphs for your TextView.

Comment: did you know any font name for this ?

Comment: Yes: It's called [Google](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=google+arabic+font)

Comment: Is doesnt work never :)

Answer (score 2):

you can convert it to HTML file and put it to assets and show it with WebView.

in your XML:

```
<WebView
  android:layout_width="match_parrent"
  android:layout_height="match_parrent"
  android:id="@+id/WV1"
/>
```

in your activity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {  

    public WebView wv;

    @Override  
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);  

        wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WV1);  
        wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myWV.html");
    }  
}
```